# In Pandas, how to get the number of unique values, up to time T?

Tags: python, pandas

consider the following dataset

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.date_range('2012-02-02','2012-02-07'),
                 'ID':['A','B','A','D','A',np.NaN]})      

df
Out[122]: 
           A    ID
0 2012-02-02    A
1 2012-02-03    B
2 2012-02-04    A
3 2012-02-05    D
4 2012-02-06    A
5 2012-02-07  NaN
```

I would like to get the number of unique values of ID, **up to time t**. That means the output should look like

```
Out[122]: 
           A    uniqueID
0 2012-02-02    1
1 2012-02-03    2
2 2012-02-04    2
3 2012-02-05    3
4 2012-02-06    3
5 2012-02-07    3
```

Indeed, on Feb 3rd, we know there are two unique values of `ID` ('A' and 'B'). On Feb 4th we see 'A', but we know that already so we don't increment our count of unique ID values.

I dont see a simple way to do so with `groupby.agg('nunique')`. Any idea is welcome.

Thanks!

EDIT:

trying to understand edchum solution...

```
df.apply(lambda x: df['ID'].iloc[:x.name+1],axis=1)
Out[134]: 
   0    1    2    3    4   5
0  A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
1  A    B  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
2  A    B    A  NaN  NaN NaN
3  A    B    A    D  NaN NaN
4  A    B    A    D    A NaN
5  A    B    A    D    A NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` a lambda that slices the df using `loc` and the row index value using `.name` and calcs the `nunique` count of ID column:

```
In [5]:
df['Unique_ID'] = df.apply(lambda x: df['ID'].loc[:x.name].nunique(),axis=1)
df
Out[5]:
           A   ID  Unique_ID
0 2012-02-02    A          1
1 2012-02-03    B          2
2 2012-02-04    A          2
3 2012-02-05    D          3
4 2012-02-06    A          3
5 2012-02-07  NaN          3
```

**EDIT**

Here's a breakdown, if we modify the df so the index is not an int generated one:

```
In [19]:
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.date_range('2012-02-02','2012-02-07'),
                 'ID':['A','B','A','D','A',np.NaN]}, index=list('abcdef'))  
df

Out[19]:
           A   ID
a 2012-02-02    A
b 2012-02-03    B
c 2012-02-04    A
d 2012-02-05    D
e 2012-02-06    A
f 2012-02-07  NaN
```

So we see that `name` in this case is in fact the row Series index value:

```
In [20]:
df.apply(lambda x: print(x.name),axis=1).tolist()

a
b
c
d
e
f
```

So we can use this to slice the df using `loc` with a range up to and including this index value:

```
In [22]:
df.apply(lambda x: print(df['ID'].loc[:x.name]),axis=1)

a    A
Name: ID, dtype: object
a    A
b    B
Name: ID, dtype: object
a    A
b    B
c    A
Name: ID, dtype: object
a    A
b    B
c    A
d    D
Name: ID, dtype: object
a    A
b    B
c    A
d    D
e    A
Name: ID, dtype: object
a      A
b      B
c      A
d      D
e      A
f    NaN
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

So you can see that from the above that we are incrementing the slice range on each row, we can then call `nunique` on this to return the number of unique values seen in this range:

```
In [24]:
df.apply(lambda x: print(df['ID'].loc[:x.name].nunique()),axis=1)

1
2
2
3
3
3
```